# JavaScript assign function within variable to click event within plugin

Tags: javascript

I have got a plugin where I assign click event functions based on a string. However I don't think I can use `Window['variable name']` as the variable is within my plugin scope not the window scope.

How would I go about assigning the EventLeft/EventRight/EventClose variable anonymous functions to the click event of the querySelectorAll loop?

```
(function() {

  // Constructor
  this.MarvLightbox = function() {

    // Initialise plugin
    this.open();
  };

  MarvLightbox.prototype.open = function() {

    setupLightbox.call(this);
  };

  function setupLightbox() {

    var createExpand = function(img) {

          // Generate lightbox HTML and append
          var instance = this,
              html = buildHTML(instance.options.html),
              EventClose = function() {
                // Do stuff
              },
              EventLeft = function() {
                // Do stuff
              },
              EventRight = function() {
                // Do stuff
              };

          // Lightbox is active
          instance.active = true;

          // Assign click events
          html.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].src = img;

          html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
            e.addEventListener('click', function() { instance[this.dataset.click]; });
          });

    }.bind(this);

  }

});
```

Comment: Please explain why you wish to close instead of just voting to close the question, you are benefitting no one.

Comment: You cannot, not like that, but furthermore the code you made will not execute at all you are missing () at the end to make the anonymus function actually happen. Within those parentheses you can pass an argument, whichever it may be, and use a parameter which you also need to setup. 

Generally speakign this is not the best way to do it. Explain a bit deeper why exactly is it you need yo use `windows['variable name']` to begin with, then i might be able to assist u.

Comment: Code was an example to show the scope, I have updated post now with what I have, well, removed the none essential parts. 

I want to assign a anonymous function to the click event by referencing it using a string.

Comment: "I want to assign an anonymous function to the click event by referencing it". You cannot reference an anonymous function, that is why it is anonymous. You have to either give it a name and call it by its name from within the scope in which it was defined, or pass it on by either a global or as a parameter, there is no way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you own answer will work it is not really readable and therefore not easy to maintain.

Store your functions in an object and use the `key` to access it.

```
var events = {
  EventClose: function() {
    instance.active = false;
    item.current = null;
  },
  EventLeft: function() {
    if (item.current !== 0) {
      item.current = item.current - 1;
    } else {
      item.current = instance.images_count;
    }
  },
  EventRight: function() {
    if (item.current !== instance.images_count) {
      item.current = item.current + 1;
    } else {
      item.current = 0;
    }
  }
}

html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', events[e.dataset.click]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why the question is so confusing. Managed to find a solution:

```
events = function(fnstring) {
  switch(fnstring) {
      case 'EventClose': (function() {
        instance.active = false;
        item.current = null;
      }()); break;
      case 'EventLeft': (function() {
        if (item.current !== 0) {
          item.current = item.current - 1;
        } else {
          item.current = instance.images_count;
        }
      }()); break;
      case 'EventRight': (function() {
        if (item.current !== instance.images_count) {
          item.current = item.current + 1;
        } else {
          item.current = 0;
        }
      }()); break;
    }
};

html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() { events(e.dataset.click); });
});
```